# Cannot create the Paypal Payflow Object in IIS7 on windows 2008

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I am transferring my website from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 IIS7.5 and i have installed the Payflow_dotnet_2 (renamed to payflow_dotnet.dll) in the SysWOW64 folder. Also did the regsam and gacutil. But when i go to run the example code which is

Set client = Server.CreateObject("PayPal.Payments.Communication.PayflowNETAPI")

I get the error
ActiveX component can't create object

Not sure what is wrong. Cannot figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Shawn